# Where does Windows place the File Explorer logs?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I presume in Event Viewer, but where does Windows place logs for File Manager.

My OS is Windows 10 Professional x64, if that makes a difference.

Windows Logs > System or Application is the most obvious, but there are other possibilities too, such as "Application and Service Logs | Microsoft | Windows" and some subfolder below that. I did not see anything stand out.

Thoughts on where to look for where File Explorer logs errors?

Comment: Are you encountering errors and are looking for where you'd find more information on those errors?

Comment: I am encountering an issue and posted question on that. I tried looking in the main application and windows logs, but did not see anything, so I thought that Windows posts File Explorer errors somewhere else. The problem posted on the other ticket deals with a "missing files" message box and inability to resize the window. As a separate thought, I was curious where Windows stores File Explorer logs, as it would be nice to know.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

> Eventvwr.msc, Windows logs, Application logs, and search for any activity under ID 1000

Answer (score 0):

Because Explorer.exe is part of the Windows operating system, I would expect to find errors and messages regarding it in System, but like you, I'd also check out Application, because Explorer.exe might not be the one throwing the error and might only be passing something along.

It should not be necessary to check other folders under the Event Viewer unless you have created custom views and filters.

The Applications and Service Logs folder contains hardware events and logs specific to applications and services, and is generally useful for more targeted diagnosis.